# Explain the use of a bit vector for determining if all characters are unique

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation, bitvector

I am confused about how a bit vector would work to do this (not too familiar with bit vectors). Here is the code given. Could someone please walk me through this?

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Particularly, what is the `checker` doing?

Comment: It's in Java but if there's something similar in C/C++ that would be more helpful for me.

Comment: This code has been taken from Cracking The Code Interview

Comment: have you tested this?  seems like it will fail to detect duplicate 'a' characters since it's set to 0 and left-shifting it will still keep it at 0.

Comment: Note that the solution is used for lower characters a-z, meaning that we are using it for finding duplicacy for 26 characters. So, int taking 32 bits can be used here. If the range had been bigger, then the solution will not work.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that if your alphabet were larger than the number of bits  used in the vector, then it would be better to use a class like BitSet?

Comment: Where people make mistake is that they confuse with the Left shift operator syntax -  it's 1 which is moved left by x(=str.charAt(i) - 'a') places NOT x's bit shifted left by 1 place.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-java/

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`int checker` is used here as a storage for bits. Every bit in integer value can be treated as a flag, so eventually `int` is an array of bits (flag). Each bit in your code states whether the character with bit's index was found in string or not. You could use bit vector for the same reason instead of `int`. There are two differences between them:

- **Size**. `int` has fixed size, usually 4 bytes which means 8*4=32 bits (flags). Bit vector usually can be of different size or you should specify the size in constructor.
- **API**. With bit vectors you will have easier to read code, probably something like this:

  `vector.SetFlag(4, true); // set flag at index 4 as true`

  for `int` you will have lower-level bit logic code:

  `checker |= (1 << 5); // set flag at index 5 to true`

Also probably `int` may be a little bit faster, because operations with bits are very low level and can be executed as-is by CPU. BitVector allows writing a little bit less cryptic code instead plus it can store more flags.

For future reference: bit vector is also known as bitSet or bitArray. Here are some links to this data structure for different languages/platforms:

- CPP: [BitSet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)
- Java: [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)
- C#: [BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) and [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

Comment: Does java has a BitVector class? I couldn't find any documentation to it!

Comment: The size has fixed size, which is 32 bits. Is that mean it can only test 32 characters' unique? I have test that, this function could test "abcdefgZZ" is false, but "abcdefg@@" return true.

Comment: Google led me here. @Dejel Here's the java data structure that you can use: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html. Hopefully this helps someone traveling through the intertubes.

Comment: @nattyddubbs, thanks, I've added this and several other links to the answer

Answer (score 288):

I have a sneaking suspicion you got this code from the same book I'm reading...The code itself here isn't nearly as cryptic as the the operators- |=, &, and << which aren't normally used by us layman- the author didn't bother taking the extra time out in explaining the process nor what the actual mechanics  involved here are.  I was content with the previous answer on this thread in the beginning but only on an abstract level. I came back to it because I felt there needed to be a more concrete explanation- the lack of one always leaves me with an uneasy feeling.

This operator << is a left bitwise shifter it takes  the binary representation of that number or operand and shifts it over however many places specified by the operand or number on the right like in decimal numbers only in binaries. We are multiplying by base 2-when we move up however many places not base 10- so the number on the right is the exponent and the number on the left is a base multiple of 2.

This operator |= (called Bitwise OR assignment) take the operand on the left and or's it with the operand on the right and assigns the result to the left operand (x |= y is equivalent to x = x | y). Similarly, the operator ('&') will 'and' the left side of the operator with the right side. This also has a Bitwise AND assignment (x &= y is equivalent to x = x & y).

So what we have here is a hash table which is being stored in a 32 bit binary number every time the checker gets or'd ( `checker |= (1 << val)`) with the designated binary value of a letter its corresponding bit it is being set to true.
The character's value is and'd with the checker (`checker & (1 << val)) > 0`)- if it is greater than 0 we know we have a dupe- because two identical bits set to true and'd together will return true or '1''.

There are 26 binary places each of which corresponds to a lowercase letter-the author did say to assume the string only contains lowercase letters- and this is because we only have 6 more (in 32 bit integer) places left to consume- and than we get a collision

```
00000000000000000000000000000001 a 2^0

00000000000000000000000000000010 b 2^1

00000000000000000000000000000100 c 2^2

00000000000000000000000000001000 d 2^3

00000000000000000000000000010000 e 2^4

00000000000000000000000000100000 f 2^5

00000000000000000000000001000000 g 2^6

00000000000000000000000010000000 h 2^7

00000000000000000000000100000000 i 2^8

00000000000000000000001000000000 j 2^9

00000000000000000000010000000000 k 2^10

00000000000000000000100000000000 l 2^11

00000000000000000001000000000000 m 2^12

00000000000000000010000000000000 n 2^13

00000000000000000100000000000000 o 2^14

00000000000000001000000000000000 p 2^15

00000000000000010000000000000000 q 2^16

00000000000000100000000000000000 r 2^17

00000000000001000000000000000000 s 2^18

00000000000010000000000000000000 t 2^19

00000000000100000000000000000000 u 2^20

00000000001000000000000000000000 v 2^21

00000000010000000000000000000000 w 2^22

00000000100000000000000000000000 x 2^23

00000001000000000000000000000000 y 2^24

00000010000000000000000000000000 z 2^25
```

So, for an input string 'azya', as we move step by step

string 'a'

```
a      =00000000000000000000000000000001
checker=00000000000000000000000000000000

checker='a' or checker;
// checker now becomes = 00000000000000000000000000000001
checker=00000000000000000000000000000001

a and checker=0 no dupes condition
```

string 'az'

```
checker=00000000000000000000000000000001
z      =00000010000000000000000000000000

z and checker=0 no dupes 

checker=z or checker;
// checker now becomes 00000010000000000000000000000001
```

string 'azy'

```
checker= 00000010000000000000000000000001    
y      = 00000001000000000000000000000000 

checker and y=0 no dupes condition 

checker= checker or y;
// checker now becomes = 00000011000000000000000000000001
```

string 'azya'

```
checker= 00000011000000000000000000000001
a      = 00000000000000000000000000000001

a and checker=1 we have a dupe
```

Now, it declares a **duplicate**

Comment: @ivan-tichy have you tested this?  seems like it will fail to detect duplicate 'a' characters since it's set to 0 and left-shifting it will still keep it at 0.

Comment: @Riz No, its always starting out with '1', the algorithm shifts 1 based on the letter. So, if the letter 'a' comes once, it will be 1, which is (....000001).

Comment: @Ivan Man, I was thinking the same thing. Even the selected answer didn't explain about the operators. Thank you for the detailed info.

Comment: Should I Assume above unique checking works only with Sorted character set (abcd...z)  ? not with (bcad...)

Comment: "I have a sneaking suspicion you got this code from the same book I'm reading" same here :) made me laugh

Answer (score 88):

I think all these answers do explain how this works, however i felt like giving my input on how i saw it better, by renaming some variables, adding some others and adding comments to it:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {

    /*
    checker is the bit array, it will have a 1 on the character index that
    has appeared before and a 0 if the character has not appeared, you
    can see this number initialized as 32 0 bits:
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
     */
    int checker = 0;

    //loop through each String character
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        /*
        a through z in ASCII are charactets numbered 97 through 122, 26 characters total
        with this, you get a number between 0 and 25 to represent each character index
        0 for 'a' and 25 for 'z'

        renamed 'val' as 'characterIndex' to be more descriptive
         */
        int characterIndex = str.charAt(i) - 'a'; //char 'a' would get 0 and char 'z' would get 26

        /*
        created a new variable to make things clearer 'singleBitOnPosition'

        It is used to calculate a number that represents the bit value of having that 
        character index as a 1 and the rest as a 0, this is achieved
        by getting the single digit 1 and shifting it to the left as many
        times as the character index requires
        e.g. character 'd'
        00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
        Shift 3 spaces to the left (<<) because 'd' index is number 3
        1 shift: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
        2 shift: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100
        3 shift: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000

        Therefore the number representing 'd' is
        00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000

         */
        int singleBitOnPosition = 1 << characterIndex;

        /*
        This peforms an AND between the checker, which is the bit array
        containing everything that has been found before and the number
        representing the bit that will be turned on for this particular
        character. e.g.
        if we have already seen 'a', 'b' and 'd', checker will have:
        checker = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001011
        And if we see 'b' again:
        'b' = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010

        it will do the following:
        00000000 00000000 00000000 00001011
        & (AND)
        00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010
        -----------------------------------
        00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010

        Since this number is different than '0' it means that the character
        was seen before, because on that character index we already have a 
        1 bit value
         */
        if ((checker & singleBitOnPosition) > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        /* 
        Remember that 
        checker |= singleBitOnPosition is the same as  
        checker = checker | singleBitOnPosition
        Sometimes it is easier to see it expanded like that.

        What this achieves is that it builds the checker to have the new 
        value it hasnt seen, by doing an OR between checker and the value 
        representing this character index as a 1. e.g.
        If the character is 'f' and the checker has seen 'g' and 'a', the 
        following will happen

        'f' = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000
        checker(seen 'a' and 'g' so far) = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000001

        00000000 00000000 00000000 00100000
        | (OR)
        00000000 00000000 00000000 01000001
        -----------------------------------
        00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001

        Therefore getting a new checker as 00000000 00000000 00000000 01100001

         */
        checker |= singleBitOnPosition;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank You!

Comment: Clear explanation..Thank you

Comment: Great explanation. Easy to understand. Thank you

Comment: That one is the best

Comment: This is very reason why comments were invented.

Comment: 122 - 97 = 25. The characterIndex range would be from 0 - 25 not 26 :)

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Thank you for this great explanation!

Comment: Wow. Rock-solid explanation. You're a wonderful teacher. Other answers did not help me in understanding anything; they were a bunch of jargons.

Answer (score 31):

I also assume that your example comes from the book [Cracking The Code Interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X) and my answer is related to this context.

In order to use this algorithm to solve the problem, we have to admit that we only are going to pass characters from a to z (lowercase).

As there is only 26 letters and these are properly sorted in the encoding table we use, this guarantees us that all the potential differences `str.charAt(i) - 'a'` will be inferior to 32 (the size of the int variable `checker`).

As explained by Snowbear, we are about to use the `checker` variable as an array of bits. Lets have an approach by example :

Let's say 
`str equals "test"`

- First pass (i = t)

> checker == 0 (00000000000000000000000000000000)

```
In ASCII, val = str.charAt(i) - 'a' = 116 - 97 = 19
What about 1 << val ?
1          == 00000000000000000000000000000001
1 << 19    == 00000000000010000000000000000000
checker |= (1 << val) means checker = checker | (1 << val)
so checker = 00000000000000000000000000000000 | 00000000000010000000000000000000
checker == 524288 (00000000000010000000000000000000)
```

- Second pass (i = e)

> checker == 524288 (00000000000010000000000000000000)

```
val = 101 - 97 = 4
1          == 00000000000000000000000000000001
1 << 4     == 00000000000000000000000000010000
checker |= (1 << val) 
so checker = 00000000000010000000000000000000 | 00000000000000000000000000010000
checker == 524304 (00000000000010000000000000010000)
```

and so on.. until we find an already set bit in checker for a specific character via the condition

```
(checker & (1 << val)) > 0
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Much better explanation than the rest IMO but one thing I still don't get is checker = 00000000000010000000000000000000 | 00000000000000000000000000010000  isn't that bitwise |= OR operator. wouldn't that pick one value or the other since? why does it use and set and both bits?

Comment: @CodeCrack you said it is bitwise OR. It compares at bit level not at bit Array level. Note : int is bit Array

Answer (score 8):

Reading Ivan's answer above really helped me, although I would phrase it somewhat differently.

The `<<` in `(1 << val)` is a bit shifting operator. It takes `1` (which in binary is represented as `000000001`, with as many preceding zeroes as you like / are allocated by memory) and shifts it to the left by `val` spaces. Since we're assuming a-z only and subtracting `a` each time, each letter will have a value of 0-25, which will be that letter's index from the right in the `checker` integer's boolean representation, since we will move the `1` to the left in `checker` `val` times.

At the end of each check, we see the `|=` operator. This merges two binary numbers, replacing all `0`'s with `1`'s if a `1` exists in either operand at that index. Here, that means that wherever a `1` exists in `(1 << val)`, that `1` will be copied over into `checker`, while all of `checker`'s existing 1's will be preserved.

As you can probably guess, a `1` functions here as a boolean flag for true. When we check to see if a character is already represented in the string, we compare `checker`, which at this point is essentially an array of boolean flags (`1` values) at the indexes of characters that have already been represented, with what is essentially an array of boolean values with a `1` flag at the index of the current character.

The `&` operator accomplishes this check. Similar to the `|=`, the `&` operator will copy over a `1` **only** if both operands have a `1` at that index. So, essentially, only flags already present in `checker` that are also represented in `(1 << val)` will be copied over. In this case, that means only if the current character has already been represented will there be a `1` present anywhere in the result of `checker & (1 << val)`. And if a `1` is present anywhere in the result of that operation, then the value of the returned boolean is `> 0`, and the method returns false.

This is, I'm guessing, why bit vectors are also called **bit arrays**. Because, even though they aren't of the array data type, they can be used similar to the way arrays are used in order to store boolean flags.

Comment: Very Helpful ,Thanks for your java info sprinkles .

Answer (score 7):

There are couple of excellent answers already provided above. So I don't want to repeat what's everything already said. But did want to add couple of things to help with the above program as I just worked through the same program and had couple of questions but after spending some time, I have more clarity on this program.

First of all "checker" is used to track the character which is already traversed in the String in order to see if there are any characters are getting repeated.

Now "checker" is an int data type so it can only have 32 bits or 4 bytes (depending upon platform) so this program can only work correctly for a character set within a range of 32 characters. That's the reason, this program subtracts 'a' from each character in order to make this program run for only lower case characters. However if you mix lower and upper case characters then it would not work.

By the way, if you do not subtract 'a' from each character (see below statement) then this program will work correctly for only String with upper case characters or String with only lower case characters. So the scope of above program increases from just lower case characters to upper case characters too but they can't be mixed together.

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

However I wanted to write a generic program using Bitwise Operation which should work for any ASCII characters without worrying about upper case, lower case, numbers or any special character. In order to do this, our "checker" should be large enough to store 256 characters (ASCII Character Set size). But an int in Java would not work as it can only store 32 bits. Hence in below program, I am using BitSet class available in JDK which can have any user defined size passed while instantiating a BitSet object.

Here is a program which does the same thing as above program written using Bitwise operator but this program will work for a String with any character from ASCII character set.

```
public static boolean isUniqueStringUsingBitVectorClass(String s) {

    final int ASCII_CHARACTER_SET_SIZE = 256;

    final BitSet tracker = new BitSet(ASCII_CHARACTER_SET_SIZE);

    // if more than  256 ASCII characters then there can't be unique characters
    if(s.length() > 256) {
        return false;
    }

    //this will be used to keep the location of each character in String
    final BitSet charBitLocation = new BitSet(ASCII_CHARACTER_SET_SIZE);

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        int charVal = s.charAt(i);
        charBitLocation.set(charVal); //set the char location in BitSet

        //check if tracker has already bit set with the bit present in charBitLocation
        if(tracker.intersects(charBitLocation)) {
            return false;
        }

        //set the tracker with new bit from charBitLocation
        tracker.or(charBitLocation);

        charBitLocation.clear(); //clear charBitLocation to store bit for character in the next iteration of the loop

    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: I was looking for this solution, however there is no need for two BitSet variables. Just the tracker is enough. Updated for loop code:

    `for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int charVal = s.charAt(i);
            if(tracker.get(charVal)) {
                return  false;
            }
            tracker.set(charVal);
        }`

Answer (score 5):

**Simple Explanation (with JS code below)**

- An integer variable per machine code is a **32-bit array**
- All bit wise operations are `32-bit`
- They're agnostic of OS / CPU architecture or chosen number system of the language, e.g. `DEC64` for JS.
- This duplication finding approach is similar to **storing characters in an array of size 32** where, we set `0th` index if we find `a` in the string, `1st` for `b` & so on.
- A duplicate character in the string will have its corresponding bit occupied, or, in this case, set to 1.
- [**Ivan has already explained**: How this index calculation works in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12811293/2458438).

**Summary of operations:**

- Perform **AND** operation between `checker` & `index` of the character
- Internally both are `Int-32-Arrays`
- It is a bit-wise operation between these 2.
- Check `if` the output of the operation was `1`
- if `output == 1`

  - The `checker` variable has **that particular index-th bit** set in both arrays
  - Thus it's a duplicate.
- if `output == 0`

  - This character hasn't been found so far
  - Perform an **OR** operation between `checker` & `index` of the character
  - Thereby, updating the index-th bit to `1`
  - Assign the output to `checker`

**Assumptions:**

- We've assumed we'll get all lower case characters
- And, that size 32 is enough
- Hence, we began our index counting from **96 as reference** point considering the **ascii** code for `a` is `97`

Given below is the **JavaScript** source code.

```
function checkIfUniqueChars (str) {

    var checker = 0; // 32 or 64 bit integer variable 

    for (var i = 0; i< str.length; i++) {
        var index = str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96;
        var bitRepresentationOfIndex = 1 << index;

        if ( (checker & bitRepresentationOfIndex) > 1) {
            console.log(str, false);
            return false;
        } else {
            checker = (checker | bitRepresentationOfIndex);
        }
    }
    console.log(str, true);
    return true;
}

checkIfUniqueChars("abcdefghi");  // true
checkIfUniqueChars("aabcdefghi"); // false
checkIfUniqueChars("abbcdefghi"); // false
checkIfUniqueChars("abcdefghii"); // false
checkIfUniqueChars("abcdefghii"); // false
```

**Note** that in JS, despite integers being of 64 bits, a bit wise operation is always done on 32 bits.

**Example:**
If the string is `aa` then:

```
// checker is intialized to 32-bit-Int(0)
// therefore, checker is
checker= 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

**i = 0**

```
str[0] is 'a'
str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96 = 1

checker 'AND' 32-bit-Int(1) = 00000000000000000000000000000000
Boolean(0) == false

// So, we go for the '`OR`' operation.

checker = checker OR 32-bit-Int(1)
checker = 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

**i = 1**

```
str[1] is 'a'
str[i].charCodeAt(0) - 96 = 1

checker= 00000000000000000000000000000001
a      = 00000000000000000000000000000001

checker 'AND' 32-bit-Int(1) = 00000000000000000000000000000001
Boolean(1) == true
// We've our duplicate now
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets break down the code line by line.

**int checker = 0;** We are initiating a checker which will help us find duplicate values.

**int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';** We are getting the ASCII value of the character at the 'i'th position of the string and subtracting it with the ASCII value of 'a'. Since the assumption is that the string is lower characters only, the number of characters in limited to 26. Hece, the value of 'val' will always be >= 0.

**if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;**

**checker |= (1 << val);**

Now this is the tricky part. Lets us consider an example with string "abcda". This should ideally return false.

***For loop iteration 1:***

Checker: 00000000000000000000000000000000

val: 97-97 = 0

1 << 0:  00000000000000000000000000000001

checker & (1 << val): 00000000000000000000000000000000 is not > 0

Hence checker: 00000000000000000000000000000001

***For loop iteration 2:***

Checker: 00000000000000000000000000000001

val: 98-97 = 1

1 << 1:  00000000000000000000000000000010

checker & (1 << val): 00000000000000000000000000000000 is not > 0

Hence checker: 00000000000000000000000000000011

***For loop iteration 3:***

Checker: 00000000000000000000000000000011

val: 99-97 = 2

1 << 2:  00000000000000000000000000000100

checker & (1 << val): 00000000000000000000000000000000 is not > 0

Hence checker: 00000000000000000000000000000111

***For loop iteration 4:***

Checker: 00000000000000000000000000000111

val: 100-97 = 3

1 << 3:  00000000000000000000000000001000

checker & (1 << val): 00000000000000000000000000000000 is not > 0

Hence checker: 00000000000000000000000000001111

***For loop iteration 5:***

Checker: 00000000000000000000000000001111

val: 97-97 = 0

1 << 0:  00000000000000000000000000000001

checker & (1 << val): 00000000000000000000000000000001 is > 0

Hence return false.

Comment: val: 99-97 = 0 should be val: 99-97 = 2 and val: 100-97 = 0 should be 3

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //In order to understand this algorithm, it is necessary to understand the following:

    //int checker = 0;
    //Here we are using the primitive int almost like an array of size 32 where the only values can be 1 or 0
    //Since in Java, we have 4 bytes per int, 8 bits per byte, we have a total of 4x8=32 bits to work with

    //int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
    //In order to understand what is going on here, we must realize that all characters have a numeric value
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        char val = (char)i;
        System.out.print(val);
    }

    //The output is something like:
    //             !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
    //There seems to be ~15 leading spaces that do not copy paste well, so I had to use real spaces instead

    //To only print the characters from 'a' on forward:
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i=0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        char val = (char)i;
        //char val2 = val + 'a'; //incompatible types. required: char found: int
        int val2 = val + 'a';  //shift to the 'a', we must use an int here otherwise the compiler will complain
        char val3 = (char)val2;  //convert back to char. there should be a more elegant way of doing this.
        System.out.print(val3);
    }

    //Notice how the following does not work:
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i=0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        char val = (char)i;
        int val2 = val - 'a';
        char val3 = (char)val2;
        System.out.print(val3);
    }
    //I'm not sure why this spills out into 2 lines:
    //EDIT I cant seem to copy this into stackoverflow!

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    //So back to our original algorithm:
    //int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
    //We convert the i'th character of the String to a character, and shift it to the right, since adding shifts to the right and subtracting shifts to the left it seems

    //if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
    //This line is quite a mouthful, lets break it down:
    System.out.println(0<<0);
    //00000000000000000000000000000000
    System.out.println(0<<1);
    //00000000000000000000000000000000
    System.out.println(0<<2);
    //00000000000000000000000000000000
    System.out.println(0<<3);
    //00000000000000000000000000000000
    System.out.println(1<<0);
    //00000000000000000000000000000001
    System.out.println(1<<1);
    //00000000000000000000000000000010 == 2
    System.out.println(1<<2);
    //00000000000000000000000000000100 == 4
    System.out.println(1<<3);
    //00000000000000000000000000001000 == 8
    System.out.println(2<<0);
    //00000000000000000000000000000010 == 2
    System.out.println(2<<1);
    //00000000000000000000000000000100 == 4
    System.out.println(2<<2);
    // == 8
    System.out.println(2<<3);
    // == 16
    System.out.println("3<<0 == "+(3<<0));
    // != 4 why 3???
    System.out.println(3<<1);
    //00000000000000000000000000000011 == 3
    //shift left by 1
    //00000000000000000000000000000110 == 6
    System.out.println(3<<2);
    //00000000000000000000000000000011 == 3
    //shift left by 2
    //00000000000000000000000000001100 == 12
    System.out.println(3<<3);
    // 24

    //It seems that the -  'a' is not necessary
    //Back to if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
    //(1 << val means we simply shift 1 by the numeric representation of the current character
    //the bitwise & works as such:
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(0&0);    //0
    System.out.println(0&1);       //0
    System.out.println(0&2);          //0
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(1&0);    //0
    System.out.println(1&1);       //1
    System.out.println(1&2);          //0
    System.out.println(1&3);             //1
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(2&0);    //0
    System.out.println(2&1);       //0   0010 & 0001 == 0000 = 0
    System.out.println(2&2);          //2  0010 & 0010 == 2
    System.out.println(2&3);             //2  0010 & 0011 = 0010 == 2
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(3&0);    //0    0011 & 0000 == 0
    System.out.println(3&1);       //1  0011 & 0001 == 0001 == 1
    System.out.println(3&2);          //2  0011 & 0010 == 0010 == 2, 0&1 = 0 1&1 = 1
    System.out.println(3&3);             //3 why?? 3 == 0011 & 0011 == 3???
    System.out.println(9&11);   // should be... 1001 & 1011 == 1001 == 8+1 == 9?? yay!

    //so when we do (1 << val), we take 0001 and shift it by say, 97 for 'a', since any 'a' is also 97

    //why is it that the result of bitwise & is > 0 means its a dupe?
    //lets see..

    //0011 & 0011 is 0011 means its a dupe
    //0000 & 0011 is 0000 means no dupe
    //0010 & 0001 is 0011 means its no dupe
    //hmm
    //only when it is all 0000 means its no dupe

    //so moving on:
    //checker |= (1 << val)
    //the |= needs exploring:

    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    System.out.println("x|=1 "+(x|=1));  //1
    System.out.println(x|=1);     //1
    System.out.println(x|=1);      //1
    System.out.println(x|=1);       //1
    System.out.println(x|=1);       //1
    System.out.println(y|=1); // 0001 |= 0001 == ?? 1????
    System.out.println(y|=2); // ??? == 3 why??? 0001 |= 0010 == 3... hmm
    System.out.println(y);  //should be 3?? 
    System.out.println(y|=1); //already 3 so... 0011 |= 0001... maybe 0011 again? 3?
    System.out.println(y|=2); //0011 |= 0010..... hmm maybe.. 0011??? still 3? yup!
    System.out.println(y|=3); //0011 |= 0011, still 3
    System.out.println(y|=4);  //0011 |= 0100.. should be... 0111? so... 11? no its 7
    System.out.println(y|=5);  //so we're at 7 which is 0111, 0111 |= 0101 means 0111 still 7
    System.out.println(b|=9); //so 0100 |= 1001 is... seems like xor?? or just or i think, just or... so its 1101 so its 13? YAY!

    //so the |= is just a bitwise OR!
}

public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    int checker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';  //the - 'a' is just smoke and mirrors! not necessary!
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean is_unique(String input)
{
    int using_int_as_32_flags = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        int numeric_representation_of_char_at_i = input.charAt(i);
        int using_0001_and_shifting_it_by_the_numeric_representation = 1 << numeric_representation_of_char_at_i; //here we shift the bitwise representation of 1 by the numeric val of the character
        int result_of_bitwise_and = using_int_as_32_flags & using_0001_and_shifting_it_by_the_numeric_representation;
        boolean already_bit_flagged = result_of_bitwise_and > 0;              //needs clarification why is it that the result of bitwise & is > 0 means its a dupe?
        if (already_bit_flagged)
            return false;
        using_int_as_32_flags |= using_0001_and_shifting_it_by_the_numeric_representation;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous Posts explain well what the code block does and i want to add my simple Solution using the BitSet java Data structure :

```
private static String isUniqueCharsUsingBitSet(String string) {
  BitSet bitSet =new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
        int val = string.charAt(i);
        if(bitSet.get(val)) return "NO";
        bitSet.set(val);
    }
  return "YES";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Line 1:   public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
Line 2:      int checker = 0;
Line 3:      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
Line 4:          int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
Line 5:          if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
Line 6:         checker |= (1 << val);
Line 7:      }
Line 8:      return true;
Line 9:   }
```

The way I understood using Javascript.  Assuming input `var inputChar = "abca"; //find if inputChar has all unique characters`

### Lets Start

`Line 4: int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';`

> Above line Finds Binary value of first character in inputChar which is **a**, **a = 97**  in ascii, then convert 97 to binary becomes  **1100001**.

In Javascript Eg: `"a".charCodeAt().toString(2)`  returns 1100001

> `checker = 0` // binary 32 bit representation = 0000000000000000000000000

`checker = 1100001 | checker;` //checker becomes 1100001 (In 32 bit representation it becomes 000000000.....00001100001)

But i want my bitmask (`int checker`) to set only one bit, but checker is 1100001

```
Line 4:          int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

> Now above code comes handy. I just subtract 97 always (ASCII val of a)

```
val = 0; // 97 - 97  Which is  a - a
val = 1; // 98 - 97 Which is b - a
val = 1;  // 99 - 97 Which is c - a
```

Lets use `val` which is resetted

Line 5 and Line 6 is well explained @Ivan answer

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone is looking for kotlin equivalent of unique characters in a string using bit vector

```
fun isUnique(str: String): Boolean {
    var checker = 0
    for (i in str.indices) {
        val bit = str.get(i) - 'a'
        if (checker.and(1 shl bit) > 0) return false
        checker = checker.or(1 shl bit)
    }
    return true
}
```

Ref: https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/bitwise